# web3js (v1.0.0-beta36) unable to use - Cannot find module 'buffer'

Tags: javascript, web3js-v1.x

I included `dist/web3.js` ([1.0.0-beta36](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/v1.0.0-beta.36)) in my html file as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Web3 = require('web3');        
    var web3 = new Web3();

    window.onload = function() {
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://api.myetherwallet.com/eth"));
        var account = web3.version;
        var balance = web3.eth.blockNumber;
        balance = 0;
    };
</script>
```

When I launch the html with Firefox/Chrome it throws exception `Error: Cannot find module 'buffer'` then follow by `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

If I downgrade the version of `web3.js` to [v0.20.6](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/v0.20.6), it functions ok. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues here:

1. `require` is a part of the Node.js module system, and will not work on standard HTML page, nor do you need it.
2. The function you want to call to get the current block number is `web3.eth.getBlockNumber()`, which is an asynchronous function, so you will also need to handle that.

Your code will work if written like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = async function () {
    var web3 = new Web3('https://api.myetherwallet.com/eth');
    var version = web3.version;
    var blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();

    console.log(version, blockNumber);

};
</script>
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/d8rus2hc/

Comment: The solution works ok with chrome browser, but with Firefox for some reason it never comes out from 'await'

Comment: I use Firefox, and it works fine for me. It could be a problem with the Web3 provider from myetherwallet, since you are querying a node and then waiting for a response. How are you testing? with the JSFiddle?

Comment: Using your example works with Firefox. If I replace the 'web3.js' pointing to my local file it will fail. The failure is caused by browser security "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". I think this is off topic, i'll accept your answer.